# How to add dynamic link to table data

Tags: reactjs, antd

I'm working on a simple table using ReactJs and ant design, my problem is I don't know how to put value on the links using their data keys.

Thanks,

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/gerryl1991/pen/vdBorw)

**SAMPLE CODE**

```
const { Table } = antd;

const columns = [{
  title: 'Name',
  dataIndex: 'name',
  render: text => <a href="#">{text}</a>,
}, {
  title: 'Cash Assets',
  className: 'column-money',
  dataIndex: 'money',
}, {
  title: 'Address',
  dataIndex: 'address',
}];

const data = [{
  key: '1',
  name: 'John Brown',
  money: '￥300,000.00',
  address: 'New York No. 1 Lake Park',
}, {
  key: '2',
  name: 'Jim Green',
  money: '￥1,256,000.00',
  address: 'London No. 1 Lake Park',
}, {
  key: '3',
  name: 'Joe Black',
  money: '￥120,000.00',
  address: 'Sidney No. 1 Lake Park',
}];

ReactDOM.render(
  <Table
    columns={columns}
    dataSource={data}
    bordered
    title={() => 'Header'}
    footer={() => 'Footer'}
  />
, mountNode);
```

Comment: Your codepen link is invalid. Show us your progress by sharing a valid link with your work so far, so thate we can help :)

Comment: sorry sir, please check the link again sir.

Comment: you want to navigate to different URLs on clicking the names, right ? eg: when "John Brown" is clicked, you need to go to `http://<some-domain>.com/user/johnbrown` ...sth like dat ?

Comment: Look at the "Simple table with actions" example:

https://ant.design/components/table/

Comment: yes @Dane.. sorry late reply

Comment: I need to put value on hrefs..

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Change this

```
render: text => <a href="#">{text}</a>
```

to this

```
render: (text, record) => <a href={'user/' + record.name}>{text}</a>
```

if you're using router

```
render: (text, record) => <Link to={'user/' + record.name}>{text}</Link>
```

Answer (score 1):

As you can see, the column rendering logic is provided by the `columns` array of objects. So if you want to include any logic ( like giving values to URLs ), you have to alter the corresponding object's `render` key:

```
const columns = [{
  title: 'Name',
  dataIndex: 'name',
  render: text => <a href={`http://<some-domain>.com/user/${text.split(' ').join()}`}>{text}</a>,   // changed function, so that data maps to links. eg: http:??<some-domain>.com/user/JohnBrown
  }, {
  /*  */
  }, {
  /*  */
}];
```

Alternatively, you could create an object for looking up urls, like so:

```
const mapping = {
  'John Brown': 'http://yourdomain.com/user/134123',
  'Jin Green': 'http://yourdomain.com/user/897983',
  /* more persons */
}

const columns = [{
  title: 'Name',
  dataIndex: 'name',
  render: text => <a href={mapping[text]}>{text}</a>,   // changed function
  }, {
  /*  */
  }, {
  /*  */
}];
```

Comment: @MarkGerrylMirandilla yes, try and let me know